# I have a requirement to write unit test using jest of a non-export typescript class methods

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

- How to access non-export typescript class in unit test file?
- How to access private static method of non-export typescript class in unit test file?

```
// SomeClass.ts
class SomeClass {
  private static someMethod() {
    // some code
 }
}

// SomeClass.test.ts >> ??
```

Comment: You can't access it and shouldn't (directly) test private methods anyway, so you should probably find out _why_ this is supposedly a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

- If you don't really care on typing, you may use `@ts-ignore`. JS will let you do whatever you want after all; (or use more safe  `as {someMethod: ()=>void}`)
- If your functions are *actually* private (start with `#`), then, well, there's absolutely nothing simple you can do with that